# ETW "connid" in network events always zero

Tags: windows, etw

According to [TcpIp MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364128(v=vs.85).aspx), In classes like [TcpIp_TypeGroup1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364129(v=vs.85).aspx), I expect a field named "connid" to be as

> A unique connection identifier to correlate events belonging to the same connection.

I start an ETW logging session to monitor network events:

```
logman start "NT Kernel Logger" -p "Windows Kernel Trace" (net) -o sys.etl -ets
```

After a while, I stop the logging session

```
logman stop "NT Kernel Logger" -ets
```

and parse the log file

```
tracerpt sys.etl
```

After opening the dumpfile, I see that all the "connid"s are zero instead of being a unique identifier.